# How to show inputField as just text on the VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks

How to show apex:inputField on the VF page with pre-defined value as just text:

In the below screenshot, the task status is shown as 'Completed', I want to do the same on the VF page that I am building:

[image]

I tried doing this `<apex:inputField value="{!Task.Status}" html-readonly= "TRUE"/>` but it shows the error :

> Cannot override attribute 'readonly' on component

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need an `<apex:outputfield value="{!Task.Status}" />`.

From [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm):

> A read-only display of a label and value for a field on a Salesforce
>   object. An  component respects the attributes of the
>   associated field, including how it should be displayed to the user.
>   For example, if the specified  component is a
>   currency field, the appropriate currency symbol is displayed.
>   Likewise, if the  component is a lookup field or
>   URL, the value of the field is displayed as a link.

Comment: Oh..I thought apex:outputField works only for the records which are saved in the DB already. But I just tried and it is working even if I set the value in controller but not yet saved to DB.

Comment: Glad this worked for you.  Please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.